# Is it possible to use a list from a text file as a list data structure?

Tags: python

We have a `states.txt` that has a list of all US states in this format:

```
state =[
'Alabama',
'Alaska',
'Arizona',
. . .
'West Virginia',
'Wisconsin',
'Wyoming'
]
```

The ellipses (. . .) is the rest of the states in the US in alphabetical order.

I'd like to use this as a list in Python:

```
state = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', . . . 'Wyoming']
```

But using `read()` returns the file as an entire string and due to the format `split()` or `strip()` do not appear to work.

Is this something that can be done? Or is the only way to copy and paste it into the `.py` directly?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can convert Python literals into Python values using `ast.literal_eval`. As opposed to `evil`, this function is safe to use. First split on `=` (only once, to make sure any states that contain an equals sign in its name are not messed up :P ) ignoring the assignment at the start, to get the pure list literal, then parse it:

```
file_contents = """
state =[
'Alabama',
'Alaska',
'Wisconsin',
'Wyoming'
]
"""

import ast

state_string = file_contents.split("=", 1)[1]
state = ast.literal_eval(state_string)
# => ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec()` to execute text as python code

```py
file_contents = """
state =[
'Alabama',
'Alaska',
'Wisconsin',
'Wyoming'
]
"""
exec(file_contents)
print(state)

/*  ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'] */
```

Comment: If you know what is in the file, you may as well have it in code instead. If you don't know what is in the file, `exec` is unsafe to use. There are very, very few situations where `eval` or `exec` are warranted.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to save it as a json array and then parse the file contents as json. Let's suppose your file is saved in json as

```json
{
    "states": ["Alabama", "Alaska"]
}
```

```py
import json
file = open('states.json', 'r')
list_of_states = json.loads(file.read())
```

Comment: You don't need to call `file.read()`. `json.load(file)` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.parse` to parse the Python statement into an AST, and output the values of the `Constant` nodes in the `List` nodes in the value of the `Assignment` node, which should be the first statement of the `Module` body:

```
import ast

data = '''state = [
'Alabama',
'Alaska'
]'''

print([node.value for node in ast.parse(data).body[0].value.elts])
```

This outputs:

```
['Alabama', 'Alaska']
```

This approach is more robust than using `ast.literal_eval` since it allows the first equal sign to be part of a comment, for example.

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/FinancialUnlawfulDividend